# Install older version of Rapids AI using Docker

Tags: rapids

how do I install an older version of Rapids AI using Docker such as 22.06? The newest version 23.02 doesn't work on any VAST AI (https://vast.ai/) machine.

Comment: why doesn't it work on vast?  what errors do you get?

Comment: When I try to run any specific rapids ai code, like reading a csv with cudf of performing PCA with cuml, It does nothing, just hangs,

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to install it by changing your docker pull parameters.  You can always find them on our dockerhub page, under tags, and searching for the version you want.  Here are the 22.06 versions.  https://hub.docker.com/r/rapidsai/rapidsai/tags?name=22.06

Comment: Thanks, an earlier version sorted out my issues.